# Using Facebook app_link_hosts API Response is 403 Permissions Error - Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I followed the Facebook API tutorial for Android to setup Facebook Login, viewing the news feed and posting a new message to Facebook.  All that works.  Now I want to associate app links to my app so deep linking works.  I changed the post code to submit a request to /app/app_link_hosts with my link in order to associate it and I get back this error response:

```
05-12 13:59:25.002: E/response(32412): {Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Permissions error}, isFromCache:false}
```

Here's my code for app_link_hosts

```
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "App Post");
    params.putString("android", "[{\"url\": \"myapp://post/" + appLinkHostId + "\",\"package\": \"com.myapp.socialnetworktest\"}]");
    params.putString("web", "{\"should_fallback\": false}");
    /* make the API call */
    new Request(
        session,
        "/app/app_link_hosts",
        params,
        HttpMethod.POST,
        new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Log.e("response", response.toString());
            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();
```

I think once I get this working I can use the url I submitted as the URL in a new Facebook Post and deep linking will work.  Is this correct?

Comment: Those calls (to `/app/app_link_hosts`) need to be made server side using the app access token - if you're making them from Android code you may be doing it wrong

Comment: I think it should be possible to call this from Android.  On this Facebook page there's instructions for Android under section publishing.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/app_link_hosts

Comment: For publishing posts with app links, yes, and there's automatically generated sample there code for many languages (and it would technically work from Android) but your call there is the one to set up the app-link-host(s) for your app. That call requires an App Access token (which makes calls on behalf of the app itself, not one of its users)- it's a relatively rarely performed operation which shouldn't be done from client code - it's likely your example was failing because you're using a user access token / session

Comment: I see on that page "Note that you can use the App Links Hosting API if you don't have a web server available to set up your App Links. This scenario is common if you have a mobile-only app."  I'm looking to use the App Links Hosting API without having to program anything server-side.  I'm not sure if I'm using the right API.

Comment: I'll follow up with the documentation team, it's not really clear from the docs how to do this, but depending on how your app works i think you should only need to call `/app/app_link_hosts` once or twice and can make those calls manually, then you use the resulting 'app link host' object in your client app when making a post which you want to be linked directly into your app using the URI scheme defined in the app link host

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  If you make the calls once or twice at startup, what would you use for the url parameter?  That parameter should be dynamic depending on what the specific post is

Comment: Sorry, I'm checking with the mobile platform team now, I appear to have misunderstood what this API is for and how it's intended to be used - I'll try to add a detailed answer once I figure this out

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Same thing here. Andy, Pls post if you could figure out the problem. @lgy, are you from Facebook ? If so, you should definitely tell your documentation team that they are suck in writing instruction. Those are not hello world thing. They are writing like a simple tutorial without saying anything about internal functionalities.