# Facebook app request doesnot redirect to play store on android

Tags: android, facebook

When I send an invite request from my app to facebook friend it gets received to the friend. But when the friend taps on the request from notification jewel in facebook android app it always opens a facebook url( This is canvas url). It never redirects to play store. The behaviours are as follows:-

1. When app is installed and the request is tapped it opens the app. (This is expected behaviour and is happening).
2. When app is not installed and the request is tapped it opens the canvas url.(The expected behaviour should be to open the play store of the app).

I have tried all combinations in app settings on facebook. But I am unable to get the expected behaviour.

In the request dialogue I set, title, message. Am I missing something in the request parameters or am I missing something in the app settings which might have been added recently?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469585/facebook-android-sdk-app-request-not-redirects-to-google-play-store. But When I followed the answer it also didn't work.

Comment: I have created a bug for this. The link is https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/615212268555401

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this after googling. We need to add mobile site url as a platform on facebook app settings. This would enable redirection to google play store. This might be an issue in facebook.

Comment: And if I have game on android and iOS then how can i redirect whether play store or app store??